# How to change state from the state object itself not outside?

Tags: c++, qt, qstatemachine

```
    class ListenState : public QState
    {
    public:
        ListenState();
        ~ListenState();

    signals:
        void nextState();

    public slots:
        void getSettings();
    };
```

The cpp file is

```
ListenState::ListenState()
{
    qDebug() << "Entering ListenState";
}

ListenState::~ListenState()
{
    qDebug() << "Leaving ListenState";
}

void ListenState::getSettings()
{
    Commands cmd;

    cmd.getSettings();

    emit exited( QEvent::None ); // i want to change state now
}
```

What I want to do is when `getSettings()` is called, I want to change the state to next one. I thought I would `emit exited()` but it doesn't build. I tried to create my own signal `nextState()` but that doesn't compile either if I emit in this function.

With above code the error is:

> ListenState.cpp:23: error: C2664: 'QAbstractState::exited' : cannot
>   convert parameter 1 from 'QEvent::Type' to
>   'QAbstractState::QPrivateSignal' No user-defined-conversion operator
>   available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be
>   called

If I emit my own signal with `emit nextState();` the error is:

> ListenState.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: void __thiscall ListenState::nextState(void)"
>   (?nextState@ListenState@@QAEXXZ)

Is there a way to trigger trasition from one state to another when I am in originating state?

Comment: What's the compilation error message?

Comment: @Andre I updated the post with error

Comment: First error is pretty straightforward - you are giving it wrong type.

emit nextState(); should work, I think. I wonder if your compilation has issues.  Are you using standard qmake? Which version of QT?

Comment: You are missing the Q_OBJECT macro in your class declaration. Without that moc will not create the code for signals / slots. This will cause linker errors because of the missing implementations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [qt signal undefined reference error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409343/qt-signal-undefined-reference-error)

Answer (score 4):

First, a state's lifetime has very little to do with when a state is entered or exited. States usually exist as long as the state machine exists, or they may be created and destroyed on-the-fly. You're hooking up a state's constructor and destructor with the expectation that they'll be invoked when a state is entered or exited. This is not the case.

To check when a state has been entered or exited, you could use the following:

```
void exposeStateTransitions(QState * state, QString name) {
  if (name.isEmpty()) name = state->objectName();
  QObject::connect(state, &QState::entered, []{
    qDebug() << "state" << name << "was entered";
  });
  QObject::connect(state, &QState::exited, []{
    qDebug() << "state" << name << "was exited";
  });
}
```

Secondly, states can only be changed by the use of the transition objects. You need to create a transition object for the desired transition, and provide a signal or an event to trigger it:

```
class ListenState : public QState {
  Q_OBJECT
  QSignalTransition m_transition;
  Q_SIGNAL void settingsTransition();
public:
  ListenState(QState * settingsTarget, QState * parent = 0) : 
    QState(parent), m_transition(this, SIGNAL(settingsTransition())
  {
    m_transition.setTargetState(settingsTarget);
    addTransition(&m_transition);
  }
  void getSettings() {
    ...
    emit settingsTransition();
  }
};
```

If you wish, you can trigger the transition on the fly, too:

```
class ListenState : public QState {
  Q_OBJECT
  QSignalTransition m_transition;
  Q_SIGNAL void settingsTransition();
public:
  ListenState(QState * parent = 0) : 
    QState(parent), m_transition(this, SIGNAL(settingsTransition())
  {
    addTransition(&m_transition);
  }
  void getSettings(QState * target) {
    ...
    m_transition.setTargetState(target);
    emit settingsTransition();
  }
};
```

You can use events instead of signals:

```
class ListenState : public QState {
  QEventTransition m_transition;
public:
  ListenState(QState * parent = 0) : 
    QState(parent), m_transition(this, QEvent::Leave) {
    addTransition(&m_transition);
  }
  void getSettings(QState * target) {
    ...
    m_transition->setTargetState(target);
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new QEvent(QEvent::Leave));
  }
};
```